# Not able to insert new line or break line in livewire flash message

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Iam working on laravel livewire framework. Iam trying to insert new-line using 
 tag in flash message. But livewire flash message not allowing me to insert new line in text message.

here is code of line which displaying flash message

```
session()->flash('message', 'Your updated profile has been received by the MySalafiSpouse team. We will get back to you shortly through email after your changes are approved on your MSS portal and (if public) your profile will also be reposted across our social media platforms!
<br> BarakAllāhu Feekum,
<br> MySalafiSpouse team');
```

Comment: How do you echo that message?

Comment: use {!! $message !!} in your blade file so that the html is not escaped.  but make sure this message can never contain any user supplied content.

Comment: can you please post complete line of code?

Comment: @Qirel i am not echoing specifically

Comment: Then how do you display it?

Comment: I would be careful with `{!! $message !!}`, and rather go with `{!! nl2br(e($message)) !!}` as that would allow newlines, but escape HTML